# Tax payment has not appeared in bank account ~20 days after filing electronically with TurboTax. What to do?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax, electronic-filing

I filed my taxes electronically with TurboTax on the TurboTax web site about 20 days ago. I owed an amount, but I can't see any tax payments appearing in my bank account now, about 20 days later.

Should I be concerned? How should I investigate it and be certain I successfully sent the tax to IRS's way? I did receive TurboTax's automatically generated confirmation of successfully completing tax filing electronically the day I did my tax on their web site.

Comment: What do you mean by "tax deduction"?

Comment: Money being shown as deducted/subtracted from my checking account by IRS.

Comment: Oh, you mean you signed up for auto debit of the tax due? You like to live dangerously I see... :-) Did you verify the account and routing numbers, and the date at which you requested the withdrawal?

Comment: https://sa.www4.irs.gov/irfof/lang/en/irfofgetstatus.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I did receive TurboTax's automatically generated confirmation of successfully completing tax filing electronically the day I did my tax on their web site.**

About 24 to 48 hours after you push the button at TurboTax the IRS should either confirm or reject the initial check of the tax documents. You should return to the TurboTax website to make sure the IRS has accepted the reutrn.

Next review either the confirmation you received when you pushed the button or the information at the TurboTax site. It should specify when the money would be withdrawn. You were given options regarding payment method and date you want to make the payment. Many people who finish their tax paperwork early, but owe money wait until the last day to submit. Now it is possible to submit paperwork early but specify a date just before the deadline.

Print out or even better save an electronic copy of the information at the TurboTax website. I have no idea how long it takes the IRS to actually pull the money from an account, once the day you specified has occurred. You have to plan as if the withdraw will happen on the exact date, but with millions of tax payers making transactions it may be delayed by a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about your United States Federal Income Tax payment or refund, the IRS has [a website for checking the status of your refund](http://www.irs.gov/Refunds).  You can check that site to see where your refund is.  If it doesn't show up on that site (assuming you provide all the information correctly), then you may want to check TurboTax to verify it was correctly submitted.

I believe that site also works for payments.  If not, [Turbotax's page](https://shop.turbotax.intuit.com/efile/efile_status_lookup.jsp) is not refund-specific (though I suspect it is just an API call to the same tool).

Comment: Based on comments, he's looking for a payment, not a refund to show up in his bank account.

Comment: I think you can use the tool anyway even if you're not owed money, but i'll amend the answer with Turbotax's direct method.

Answer (score 1):

I called the IRS and they stated it may take up to 45 days to withdraw the cash, but the proceeds would be applied on the date of the filing (Or when the amount was stated to be debited). Federal and State taxes differ in timelines but as long as deadlines are met and proof exists IRS does not penalize.